# PHP: how are query results stored in mysqli_result

Tags: php, memory, mysqli

When I made a query to the database and retrieve the results in mysqli_result, the memory usage is extremely small. However, when I fetch all the rows in the query results in to an associative array, the memory usage  becomes extremely high.

```
<?php
    require_once("../config.php"); //db connection config
    $db = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DBASE);

    $query ="select * from table_name";
    if($r = $db->query($query)){
    echo "MEMORY USAGE before :  ". memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){

        $rows[]= $row;
    }
    echo "MEMORY USAGE after :  ". memory_get_usage()."<br><br>";


    //before: 660880
    //after:  114655768
    // # of records: around 30 thousands
?>
```

It makes sense to me that storing this many results is very memory consuming, but I'm just wondering how come mysqli_result is so small. It can't be that the results are queried to the dbase every time fetch_assoc is called. So then where are the results stored in the memory.

Comment: I read somewhere that the `mysql_*` functions fetch all of the result rows from the server at once. However PDO (and likely mysqli) retrieve each row on demand. So with every call to fetch, you are going to use up a little memory. But you store each row in an array, so it makes sense that your memory usage will accumulate.

Comment: Do you mean that with each call to fetch, mysqli will query the database for the result?

Comment: From my understanding, when you call `query()` MySQL performs the query and prepares to return all of the result rows to PHP. However, if mysqli is like PDO (at least the default of PDO), then it won't start receiving rows until you call fetch. Unless you call `fetchAll()`, each row will be retrieved one at a time. This means your memory usage is because you saved the results in an array, not because of mysqli.

Comment: You might want to look at [`free()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php). I think your array storage is biasing the results. Try also measuring memory usage after calling `free()`. Then you can observe how much of the memory was actually used by mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a HUGE difference between fetching results and storing a pointer to a resource.

If you `echo $r;` before your first call to `memory_get_usage();`, you will realize it is just a pointer. This is the pointer to your result set. Until you `fetch` your results, the result set will not actually be stored into memory.

I would suggest that you run `fetchAll()` for what you are trying to do. This will then result in 1 method accessing all your results with better performance since it's pawned off on the mysqli extension (C Library) rather than a loop in PHP.

You can also use the free results function to clear your results from memory when you are done with them. This is like closing a cursor in Java if you are familiar.

Comment: So, why isn't the resource actually added to the memory usage? The resource is using memory space... Or is it written to disk or something?

Comment: By echo'ing `$r` before you call fetch, MySQL would have allocated space for the query results, but not PHP. PHP will only assign the results to it's memory space when you call fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to this instead:

```
while($row = $r->fetch_assoc()){
   //Do whatever you need with the record, then:
   unset($row);
}
```

The way you posted is gathering a huge array in `$rows`, and memory usage reflects that.

Comment: I know what you mean and that's definitely the original intention for fetch_assoc(). The problem is that I'm going to fetch the result and do something with it and pass it to view (in MVC sense) to display the records. I guess I could change my implementation so that one record is passed to view at a time.

Comment: Thanks. It's a problem because i've been trying to avoid having view directly communicate with models so I also have a controller in between to pass data around. What I need to do then is to create really small view template to display each record...

Comment: @spchuang if you have ~30k records it seems like you should implement some sort of pagination. Whether using paging links or an endless page solution. Also, from my understanding of the MVC pattern, the view should not communicate with the model.